# Adding one hour on date time, with AM PM in count

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, stored-procedures

I want to get the data between 2 dates, I have a procedure that takes `fromDate` as input, for example like if I give this date for it `2022/02/02 9:10:36 PM`, and I want to add 3 hours to the `ToDate`, so it should be like that: `2022/02/02 12:10:36 AM`

I tried `DATE_ADD('2022/02/02 9:10:36 PM', INTERVAL +3 Hour)` but it didn't work it gave it PM and it should be AM since its 12 AM after adding 3 hours to 9 pm.

SUMMARY: I want to get data with 3 hour range in procedure `2022/02/02 9:10:36 ((PM))` to `2022/02/02 12:10:36 ((AM))`, the procedure take the from date and i want to add three hours with AM PM in count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to convert the string date to an actual datetime type and then add the hours. Use `str_to_date()` which allows you to tell the conversion process what the string looks like so it can complete the conversion correctly.

Here is a simple demo

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2022/02/02 9:10:36 PM', '%Y/%m/%d %h:%i:%s %p') original, 
        DATE_ADD( STR_TO_DATE('2022/02/02 9:10:36 PM', '%Y/%m/%d %h:%i:%s %p') , INTERVAL +3 Hour) new_dt;
```

RESULT

```
original             new_dt
2022-02-02 21:10:36  2022-02-03 00:10:36
```

It is best to store dates and times in the appropriate data type in the first place so functions work correctly automatically. If your location requires a specific presentation of the date, do that conversion in the presentaion layer not the storage layer